# React components won't render unless browser is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, components, render

My app is working fine except when I load a page, react components don't show up at all, instead, I see an empty page. It's only when I refresh the page then I see all my react components.

How can I edit it such that the react components load when the page loads and not after I have refreshed the page?

My app uses axios to get data from ruby backend which looks something like this inside the Home component:

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`/api/v1/todo_lists/${this.state.todo_list_id}/todo_items.json`)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ todo_items: response.data })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
    }
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button className="newTodoListButton" onClick={this.addNewTodoList} >
                        New Todo List
                    </button>
                </div>
                {this.state.todo_lists.map((todo_list) => {
                    if (this.state.editingTodoListId === todo_list.id) {
                        return (<TodoListForm todo_list={todo_list} key={todo_list.id} updateTodoList={this.updateTodoList}
                            titleRef={input => this.title = input} />)
                    } else {
                        return (<TodoBox todo_list={todo_list} key={todo_list.id} onClick={this.enableEditing}
                            onDelete={this.deleteTodoList} />)
                    }
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

This is how I render the react to the page via index.js pack:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Home />,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

And this is how the index.html.erb looks like:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>
```

Comment: Try using the React Redirect and Router to load your component instead let's see if that helps. use <Redirect to="/home" /> in place of the <Home /> and to load the component when the url has changed with <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />. That way, it refreshes and loads. 

This may not be a wonderful solution but might just work! :)